# How to set the desired size of a QMainWindow with QScrollArea?

Tags: qt, size, pyqt, qmainwindow

I am working on a project where I have to display a pretty large (vertically) main Widget.
In the initial Version of my GUI it was just added as the central Widget of a QMainWindow, which caused the Problem that on small screen resolutions the controls on the Bottom of the Widget are unreachable.
To solve this i wrapped a QScrollArea around the main Widget, but now the main window is always relatively small even if it doesn't have to.

What do i need to change so the Main Windows (vertical) size is large enough to show all the contents unless it would be too large for the screen resolution? Also I don't want it to be stretched, so simply always using the whole vertical screen resolution is not an option. Ideally the size should be fixed to the size needed by the contents (w/o the scroll area) and only smaller where needed.

Overriding the sizeHint method did only resulted in a small enlargement of the Window and setting the minimal height brings me back to the beginning where some of the controls are not assessable on small resolutions.

Since i am new to QT I am actually out of ideas how to google the solution because most Solutions I can find are about sizing components inside a Window and not the Window itself.

Answer (score 0):

By default a QScrollArea will not attempt to expand to fit its contents. In order to do this you will need to re-implement QScrollArea's sizeHint() to return the size of QScrollArea's child widgets.

In your question it sounds like you were trying to re-implement MainWindow's sizeHint? re-implementing sizeHint on the top-level window will have no effect as sizeHint designed for use with widgets inside layouts.